# The Coloring Rows With N colors in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, client-side, graph-coloring

I have an HTML table, that is dynamically rewritten by external code.

The first column is a grouping column, and rows in the same group are always consecutive.

When dynamic filters are applied, all rows that don't match the filter are hidden by third-party. Order never changes.

The problem is the client wants to have lines separating the groups, but rows devised to do that disappear when filtering kicks in.

At the moment I resolved this by adding "row-group-N" class to rows, as they generate, and writing this CSS:

```
.row                        {border-top: 1px solid black}
.row-group-N + .row-group-N {border-top: none}
```

(with N being group counter modulo `Max`)

**Edit:**

Here's a demonstration: https://plnkr.co/edit/Zzh9olmmLafs1Y8lCoZB?p=preview

Max is here set to three. Bold row signifies beginning of the group, as per CSS. When you search for 'things', you'll see that the result is incorrect, due to classes wrapping around.

**End of edit**

It works by adding the separator to every element, but removing it when consecutive elements belong to the same group. But there is **worst case 1/`Max` chance of the line not showing in correct place. This is because I always have a finite number of CSS classes for this purpose.**

I'm looking for a way, myself, to determine when the filtering code finishes execution, as to be able to perform the changes then with JavaScript.

But **is there something else I can do?**

Comment: It seems like js is the only thing you can do here.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't got your requirement, feels like too much of theory.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is one where adding some kind of visualization may help you get some good answers.

Comment: @BjornJohnson Added a sample demonstrating my problem

Comment: I have issues understanding your problem, but maybe [this article](http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css) can point you in the right direction?

Comment: If you always have 3 in group, than put line/border for `table.dataTable tr:nth-child(3n) td`.

Comment: @skobaljic that's not the case

Comment: I believe @Chris is correct.  JS is the way to go.  I do not think there is an obvious way to address this, especially since you are receiving that table HTML.